# uWSGI server does not respond

Tags: python, django, linux, debian, uwsgi

I'm trying to run a Django application using Nginx + uWSGI with no success.
After hours of googling and debugging I made the simplest possible uwsgi configuration that must work:

```
$ uwsgi --http 127.0.0.1:8000 --wsgi-file test.py
```

Where test.py is

```
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return "Hello World"
```

The problem is: it doesn't. A wget call on the same machine hangs:

```
$ wget http://127.0.0.1:8000
--2013-04-28 12:43:36--  http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

uWSGI output is silent (except for initial information):

```
*** Starting uWSGI 1.9.8 (32bit) on [Sun Apr 28 12:43:56 2013] ***
compiled with version: 4.4.5 on 28 April 2013 06:22:28
os: Linux-2.6.27-ovz-4 #1 SMP Mon Apr 27 00:26:17 MSD 2009
...
```

The connection is in fact established, because killing uWSGI aborts wget.

Probably uWSGI isn't detailed enough about occurred errors, or I must've missed something.
Any tip of where to look further is appreciated.

#### Update:

More system details: Debian 6.0.7, Python 2.6.6.

A full uWSGI log on start:

```
$ uwsgi --http 127.0.0.1:8000 --wsgi-file test.py
*** Starting uWSGI 1.9.8 (32bit) on [Mon Apr 29 04:50:03 2013] ***
compiled with version: 4.4.5 on 28 April 2013 06:22:28
os: Linux-2.6.27-ovz-4 #1 SMP Mon Apr 27 00:26:17 MSD 2009
nodename: max.local
machine: i686
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: /home/user/dir
detected binary path: /home/user/dir/env/ENV/bin/uwsgi
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
uWSGI http bound on 127.0.0.1:8000 fd 4
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 19523)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:57919 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 27 2010, 00:18:12)  [GCC 4.4.5]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x80f6240
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 63944 bytes (62 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x80f6240 pid: 19522 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 19522, cores: 1)
```

And nothing else is ever printed.

Comment: Please report the full uWSGI startup logs, the example you reported should work everywhere (unless you are using python3 that requires a different return object) but maybe there is some other problem. From what you describe it looks like some kind of firewall is up on your system, but it would be strange on 127.0.0.1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who may encounter this problem too here're final results of my investigation:
the issue is definitely environment-related, and most probably Linux kernel specific.
The strace util showed that uWSGI couldn't receive a single byte - it is a kernel level.

I think that key line is

```
os: Linux-2.6.27-ovz-4
```

The Linux is running in a virtual environment and 2.6.27 is not a default kernel version for Debian 6.0.7. In 2.6.32-5 everything worked perfectly.

I don't know if it is a bug of an old kernel, or uWSGI compatibility, or both. But updating the kernel helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the exact same symptoms, after having installed uwsgi with `pip`.

I solved the problem by reinstalling uwsgi from the tarball, i.e. according to the [docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html) with

```
wget http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-latest.tar.gz
tar zxvf uwsgi-latest.tar.gz
cd <dir>
make
```

This resulted into a uwsgi binary, that when used to run the docs example you mention printed a log that only differed to the log of the pip-based version uwsgi in the python version used -- executable version was the same `(uWSGI 2.0.13.1, 64bit)`. The tarball-based version used Python 2.7.6, while the pip-based version used Python 3.4.3 . The version installed as the default, i.e. the version where the `/usr/bin/python` symbolic link points to, was Python 2.7.6 on my system.

It turns out that this wasn't at all a coincidence, as changing temporarily the `/usr/bin/python` link to Python 3.4.3 (and changing the return object in `test.py` for Python 3), made the pip-based executable work.

The bottom line is that you should **check that the Python version at the uwsgi log coincides with the default version of your system**. I'm not suggesting that installing from the tarball is better than installing from pip here; my guess that it was coincidental that the one source had the correct Python version while the other didn't. So one way to solve this problem is to **try another way to install uwsgi**.

Answer (score -1):

I've never written a bare-bones WSGI application, but looking at various tutorials it seems that you should return a list or a generator: either

```
return ['Hello world']
```

or

```
yield 'Hello world'
```

Comment: I took the example from [the doc](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html?highlight=nginx), so it should work. In worst case it would've resulted in exception.